# How can I select from a set of fixed values?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

If my capsule has a requirement to allow a user to select from a set of fixed values represented by an `enum`, how can I do that in Bixby?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are going to represent the fixed values as an enum

```
enum (FixedValue) {
  symbol (ONE)
  symbol (TWO)
  symbol (THREE)
  symbol (FOUR)
}
```

The Action file will look like this

```
action (GetFixedValue) {
 type(Search)
 description (Allow user to choose a value from the set of fixed values)

 collect{
   input (fixedValue) {
     type (FixedValue)
     min (Required) max (One)
     prompt-behavior (AlwaysElicitation)
     default-init {
       intent {
       goal: FixedValue
       value-set {FixedValue {FixedValue(ONE) FixedValue(TWO) FixedValue(THREE) FixedValue(FOUR) }}
     }
    }
   }
  } output (FixedValue)
}
```

The Javascript file for this action is as follows:

```
module.exports.function = function GetFixedValue (fixedValue) {
 return JSON.stringify(fixedValue)
}
```